# MySQL query within another query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index), ([server-side processing](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)). The problem is that it limits the way you can form your query. The default method looks like this.

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
```

Is it possible to use my own complex query (which may contain a where clause, join and so on) while still working with this constraint? I need to be able to just 'pop in' a different query depending on the situation, instead of having to rewrite the whole thing each time.

I want to have just one file that handles request for several DataTables and only change the SQL. If it's not clear please comment.

Comment: Yikes! this is a security nightmare.

Comment: what do you mean? And could somebody help me figure out why my question already has two negative votes??

Comment: By the way, that is exactly how it's posted on the official site: http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: +1 to balance the down-voters who did not bother to explain.

Comment: never used this plugin, so i don't know how to change the query. but i think you can create view an use as a table by this plugin

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe there is no SQL solution to this. I may have to create a function to modify the whole thing depending on my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your script needs to return a json list of records, while taking into account http request parameters:

- filter (sSearch)
- sorting (iSortCol_* )
- current page (iDisplayStart & iDisplayLength)

It also needs to return number of total records after the filter is applied.

How you produce that list on the serverside it is up to you, you can write queries as complex as you wish.

One way to allow more complex queries while still minimizing boilerplate code would be to wrap the functionality of example in the class, but to extract select and count queries into methods. Base class would return queries as in your example, but you would be able to override that in subclasses, and return queries as complex as you wish. But you would need to be careful to take into account filter, sort and page parameters while generating them.